# How to retrieve full Zend_Http_Client GET URI?

Tags: php, zend-http-client

I have something like that:

```
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://www.site.com');
    $client->setParameterGet(array(
        'platform'     => $platform,
        'clientId'     => $clientId,
        'deploymentId' => $deploymentId,
    ));

    try {
        $response = $client->request();
        ...
```

This would generate a request similar to 'http://www.site.com/?plataform=..?clientid?..'.
Is there a way I could retrieve this full URL generated by this GET request?
Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly enough there is no direct method for getting full request string.
BUT

1. After the request is done you could check $client->getLastRequest
   ().
2. <strike>If you need to know what the ?plataform=..?clientid? part of the
   request is there is a trick.</strike>

---

```
function getClientUrl (Zend_Http_Client $client)
{
    try
    {
        $c = clone $client;
        /*
         * Assume there is nothing on 80 port.
         */
        $c->setUri ('http://127.0.0.1');

        $c->getAdapter ()
            ->setConfig (array (
            'timeout' => 0
        ));

        $c->request ();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $string = $c->getLastRequest ();
        $string = substr ($string, 4, strpos ($string, "HTTP/1.1\r\n") - 5);
    }
    return $client->getUri (true) . $string;
}

$client = new Zend_Http_Client ('http://yahoo.com');
$client->setParameterGet ('q', 'search string');

echo getClientUrl ($client);
```

Comment: "There is a trick" or "is tricky"? :) Thanks anyway. I am amazed nobody ever had such need... might even worth to rewrite the whole class and add such functionality...

Comment: It's a tricky trick. I can give you a clue, if you're interested.

Comment: Oh, yes please! It would help me a lot! :)

Comment: The idea was to open connection to the server itself and read HTTP header from the socket. But I forgot that I can't have threads in PHP, and Zend_Http_Client will block script execution. Thus, only firs method remains.

Comment: However, if you don't want to initiate a request to remote server, you can create dumb service on your own server, and retrieve $client->getLastRequest () afterward.